# Recovering orphaned content from deactivated users in SO teams

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Something that's come up during our trial of SO Teams: if we have an accepted answer from a user, and we deactivate that user, is there any way for a team admin to reassign that answer to another user, or otherwise open up the answer for editing?

Alternatively, is there a way for admins to reassign all of a user's content to another user on deactivation?

Comment: Are orphaned posts closed for editing?

Comment: @yivi I suppose you need either the editing privilege or you can suggest them only...

Comment: @MEE If the team _itself_ has not been abandoned, that should be more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm pretty confident that team admins can't do that.

Teams is heavily based on the public Stack Overflow system and there you have to contact Stack Exchange so they can perform an account merge.

So on public Stack Overflow, only Stack Exchange employees (I assume the community moderators can do that, but not sure either) can perform such an action, but not site moderators. It wouldn't wonder me if it's the same for Teams.

At best you try and ask if they can merge those two accounts on Teams.